# O que sinalizar em uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Tenho feito várias edições e sinalizações ultimamente, mas sempre fico na dúvida quanto a escolha da sinalização correta.

Explicando mais ou menos, o que entendo de algumas das opções:

- **rude ou abusivo**: quando a pessoa é ignorante ou faz comentários pejorativos sobre alguém/algum assunto;
- **deveria ser fechada**:

  - **fora de escopo**: quando a pergunta é uma dúvida sobre "qual a melhor IDE de tal linguagem" ou "como atualizar um *app* na *Play Store*", por exemplo;
  - **não está clara o suficiente**: quando a pergunta está confusa, sem muita explicação do problema ou apenas com o código solto e/ou uma imagem;
  - **ampla demais**: quando perguntas de vários tópicos diferentes são feitas, tipo "qual a melhor IDE para aprender Java e como posso colocar meu *app* na *Apple Store*"

Basicamente tenho duas dúvidas:

- Esses meus conceitos estão corretos? Posso continuar utilizando eles para sinalizar?
- Uma questão específica, como alguém pedir um código pronto (tipo "tarefa de classe"), eu posso considerar como **rude ou abusivo**? Ou seria **fora do escopo**?

Comment: Sempre pode-se debater isto. É quase isto. Parte do que você acha que é fora de escopo geralmente é baseada em opinião. A imagem em si não é um problema de não clareza. Seu conceito de ampla demais está amplo e duplicado :) Pedir tarefa de escola sem nem tentar costuma ser fora de escopo, em alguns casos pode ser amplo. Não é rude ou abusivo.

Comment: Em casos **extremamente extremos**, você poderia considerar como rude ou abusivo, mas em geral é como **fora do escopo**, já que o site *"o site não é um serviço de encomendas de ferramentas, e sim para ajudar a tirar dúvidas e resolver problemas a quem faz ferramentas"*.

Comment: Ultimamente respondi uma pergunta corrigindo o que estava errado no código html que a pessoa passou e explicando como deveria ser o js, ela não entendeu, expliquei de novo não entendeu fui obrigado a fazer todo o código para a pessoa ou a explicação iria levar meses só assim ela conseguiu entender..

Answer (score 4):

> Esses meus conceitos estão corretos? Posso continuar utilizando eles
>   para sinalizar?

Sim. Esses critérios estão corretos.

> Uma questão específica, como alguém pedir um código pronto (tipo
>   "tarefa de classe"), eu posso considerar como rude ou abusivo? Ou
>   seria fora do escopo?

Pedir código pronto é fora de escopo, mas não é rude ou abusivo. Já que o texto da opção para tal sinalização diz:

*"Uma pessoa sensata acharia este conteúdo inapropriado para uma discussão respeitosa."*

Então, pedir código pronto não se encaixaria no critério acima. Poderia ser considerado um "abuso" num certo ponto de vista, mas não é desrespeitoso ou inapropriado.

No máximo seria fora de escopo já que na **[página Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)** diz claramente que:

*Concentre sua atenção em perguntas sobre um **problema real** que você enfrentou. Inclua detalhes sobre o que você tentou e exatamente o que você está tentando fazer.*

Note que até é destacado em negrito o trecho: "*problema real*".

Geralmente tais perguntas são feitas por usuários novos e que dificilmente serão usuários participativos. Eles entram apenas para resolver um problema e em seguida somem. Acharam o site no Google ou coisa assim.

Mas o que "mata" tais perguntas de faculdade ou exercícios é o usuário mencionar isso. Talvez, se não mencionassem, haveria chances (embora, ainda, poucas) da pergunta ser bem recebida. Contudo, em muitos casos e, dependendo do caso, a pergunta é respondida por algum usuário que se prontificou em dar o "código pronto", se a pergunta não fora fechada antes.

O sistema de sinalização e de votos existe para isso. Se perguntas desse tipo não foi fechada, supõe-se que a comunidade não quis fechá-la.

Comment: Podia ter comentado na outra pergunta que respondeu essa, só vi agora. Uma dúvida em relação a pergunta, rude ou abusivo eu concordo ser incorreto, porém me fica a dúvida em relação a ampla demais ou fora do escopo ou até mesmo não clara o suficiente, por que uma e não outra?