# O que fazer com perguntas não respondidas no meta?

Tags: debate, suporte, meta, perguntas-sem-resposta

Estava pesquisando sobre uma dúvida em relação SOpt (qual a sinalização correta para perguntas do tipo "faz pra mim"?) e encontrei uma [pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6332) que é parecida com a minha (um pouco mais ampla), a mesma tem comentários que ajudam, porém não possui uma resposta mais completa (na verdade, nenhuma resposta)

O que fazer? Criar mais uma? De repente o meta não poderia ter uma aba destaque?

Comment: No meta nem toda pergunta é uma pergunta, e nem toda resposta "completa" é uma resolução de fato, só analisando uma a uma, algumas são esquecidas mesmas, outras são impossiveis de afirmar devido a situações de ausência de um feedback dos CMs (funcionários da SO). Resumindo: só analisando caso a caso.

Comment: Não seria melhor linkar essas duas perguntas relacionadas na pergunta ? Assim fica mais claro.

Comment: @Isac editei a pergunta adicionado o principal, não tinha colocado antes por querer uma resposta mais geral, não só pra esse caso específico

Comment: Vc pode sozinho pesquisar e postar uma resposta.

Comment: @sam pesquisar aonde? Quando eu não sei algo relacionado ao funcionamento do site pergunto no meta, se não tiver no meta (ou em algum manual - tour, central de ajuda, ...), aonde mais pode estar?

Comment: No rodapé do site tem um link "Ajuda" com muita informação.

Comment: E parece que a ironia atacou novamente. A pergunta no meta sobre perguntas não respondidas no meta não tem respostas.